# how to submit something through DELETE HTTP verb

Tags: html, http, http-verbs

how to send data or submit to URL through DELETE HTTP verb, what is the gain of it and what about browsers support?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

While it is unclear exactly what you're asking (more detail would be useful), this page has a little summary of various methods: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Basically:

GET: Only function is to send information back to the client. It should be a repeatable  operation without any side effects, or changes.

POST: It does operations with side effects. It is not repeatable  (if you POST twice, the server acts twice). After operation it should redirect to another page to show the results using the GET method.

DELETE: Its only function is to do a destructive operation, not repeatable (once the object is deleted, there is nothing else to delete).

PUT: Its function is to modify a single object and update it with the values sent in a POST (like) way. Repeatable.

Comment: so, how can I use DELETE verb?

Comment: What were you looking to accomplish? I haven't found a use for it myself, but if you were looking for what it can do, this is a good article: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp